# Apache + PHP-FPM Set proxy timeout only to specific path

Tags: timeout, php, mod-proxy

I have Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.5 without using php_mod but with PHP-FPM and mod_proxy_fcgi, so I added the following to the vhost:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:7000/home/var/www/site/$1
```

This worked well but when I had some problems with timeouts I added the following code in order to fix this issue to the vhost file:

```
<Proxy fcgi://127.0.0.1:7000>
    ProxySet timeout=3600
</Proxy>
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:7000/home/var/www/site/$1
```

However, I would like to add this timeout only to the administration panel of the website, which is www.site.com/admin/xxx. I tried to add the location tag like below, but it didn't worked (Apache fails when restarting).

```
<LocationMatch ^/admin/.*\.php(/.*)?$>
    <Proxy fcgi://127.0.0.1:7000>
        ProxySet timeout=3600
    </Proxy>
</LocationMatch >
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:7000/home/var/www/site/$1
```

First of all, is that possible? Then which would be the correct syntax?

Many thanks for your time

Comment: Why are You trying to set timeout on admin page? :). I know this question is a little stupid, but maybe there is another way / layer solution to achieve your needs.

Comment: Probably because he wants to keep the protection of a low timeout on the public site, but allow longer-running administrative panel pages. So he's not trying to "set" an admin timeout, he's trying to "extend" it from the default.

Answer (score 1):

## Just use the [Proxy wildcard](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxy) with `/admin/*`

While this will allow ANY script beneath admin to run with the settings defined, behind an admin (and I assume login) wall, it shouldn't be an issue.

```
<Proxy "fcgi://127.0.0.1:7000/home/var/www/site/admin/*">
    ProxySet timeout=3600
</Proxy>
```

## Use [ProxySet](http://ProxySet%20%22ajp://backend:7001%22%20timeout=15) outside of a Proxy directive

`ProxySet` within a Proxy directive can be used without defining the url/balancer/worker. But, you *should* still be able to use ProxySet within a Location directive.

```
<LocationMatch ^/admin/.*\.php(/.*)?$>
    ProxySet "fcgi://127.0.0.1:7000" timeout=3600
</LocationMatch>
```

If apache is still failing on startup, check the apache logs, or run `strace -Ff apachectl start` to find the problem, it may just be a bug in that version of apache.

However, I strongly suspect your LocationMatch regex `^/admin/.*\.php(/.*)?$` to be the cause of the apache failure.